# Minimising training error with a linear classifier

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I'm trying to find a linear classifier that minimises training error (0/1 loss), in cases where the data is non-linearly separable. Specifically, I'm looking for a way of determining weights:

```
sign(weights' * features) = label
```

for `features` \in {0, 1}^d, `label` \in {-1, 1} and real-valued weights. I have N training instances, and I want the above equation to hold for the maximum possible number of instances. I know something like a hard-margin SVM would work if the problem was always separable, but I also need to find a solution when it is not.

(This task may sound a bit esoteric, but please don't advise me on what to do instead of looking for a minimum-training-error linear classifier - what I have described is definitely the problem that I want to solve!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab includes a non-linear SVM toolbox that's really easy to use.
Have a look at `svmtrain` and `svmclassify`.
To select the kernel function you have to use the `'kernel_function'` argument, although the default is `'linear'` which is what you're trying to do.
The `'boxconstraint'` argument let's you select `C` which is the parameter for the soft constraint.

**Edit**

I have found [this](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/20237/1/Li2007p85212007_Ieee_International_Joint_Conference_On_Neural_Networks_Vols_1-6.pdf) paper which describes a method to minimize the 0/1 loss.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really help, unless you have some guidance for what value of C corresponds to minimising the training error (as I understand it, this would depend on the problem).

Comment: I we need to know what measure you use for training error. But I would consider not minimizing the training error but using [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) and taking the validation error as a measure.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I'm interested in 0/1 loss. As I said in my question, I very specifically want to do exactly what I described, not cross-validation.

Comment: Minimizing o/1 loss is more difficult. I have found [this](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/20237/1/Li2007p85212007_Ieee_International_Joint_Conference_On_Neural_Networks_Vols_1-6.pdf) paper which describes a method to do this. It's quite recent and I'm not sure if it's in the publicly available. I'm sorry if isn't.

Comment: Ah, that looks like what I wanted to know, thanks! Could you edit your answer to include that information so that I can accept it please?